# Impact of log_duration in PostgreSQL performance

Tags: postgresql, confluence, postgresql-9.6

All,

I'm trying to understand the impact of PostgreSQL server setting log_duration. Would it cause any performance issues setting it to ON. I was trying to setup a confluence server with Postgres backend. When this value is set as ON, the response of the service is slow, whereas when I set it to OFF, it is fast.

log_min_duration_statement is set to -1 => No query texts should be logged.

Queries:

1. Why it is slow when it is set to ON
2. Logging => does it log in any log file? If yes, where to find the same in server
3. There is another feature pg_stat_statements.track, which can be set to TOP, ALL. Why setting this is not giving performance issue. It is also tracking queries. But, it gives total_time and calls, but not individual.

Could some one help me understand the impact.

Answer (score 1):

refer to this, let me know if you need more info:

[log min duration](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=6e3e6cc0e884a6091e1094dff29db430af08fb93)

This allows logging a sample of statements, without incurring excessive
log traffic (which may impact performance).  This can be useful when
analyzing workloads with lots of short queries.

The sampling is configured using two new GUC parameters:

- log_min_duration_sample - minimum required statement duration
- log_statement_sample_rate - sample rate (0.0 - 1.0)

Only statements with duration exceeding log_min_duration_sample are
considered for sampling. To enable sampling, both those GUCs have to
be set correctly.

The existing log_min_duration_statement GUC has a higher priority, i.e.
statements with duration exceeding log_min_duration_statement will be
always logged, irrespectedly of how the sampling is configured. This
means only configurations

log_min_duration_sample < log_min_duration_statement

do actually sample the statements, instead of logging everything.

Comment: Note that `log_statement_sample_rate` was introduced in Postgres 12, but Karthik Ramachandran uses 9.6

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know is to measure it.

For simple select-only queries, such as `pgbench -S`, the impact is quite high.  I get 22,000 selects per second with it off, and 13,000 with it on.  For more complex select queries or for DML, the percentage impact will be much less.

Formatting and printing log messages, and the IPC to the log collector, take time.  pg_stat_statements doesn't do that for every query, it just increments some counters.

Of course log_duration logs to a log file (or pipe), otherwise there wouldn't be any point in turning it on.  The location is highly configurable, look in postgresql.conf for things like log_destination, log_directory, and log_filename.  (But if you don't know where to find the logs, why would you even bother to turn this logging on in the first place?)